# Enumerate all windows which are "always on top"

Tags: c#, windows, window, kill-process

I want to write a utility for our web test server which kills all processes having an "always on top" window. I guess it is window style `WS_EX_TOPMOST`, however, I'm not 100% sure.

Is there a way in C#:

- to enumerate all windows which are "always on top"
- and to retrieve the corresponding process?

Comment: So you want to check every process and see if it has a window with a Always on Top flag?

Comment: I would prefer a more performant, direct, way. If Windows does not provide such a way, I guess, I have to do that...

Comment: pinvoke EnumWindow and check WS_EX_TOPMOST

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a working example which finds all processes which have a topmost window. Be careful though: Windows Explorer always has a topmost window and you probably **don't** want to kill that process.

```
class Program
{
    const int WS_EX_TOPMOST = 0x00000008;
    const int WS_VISIBLE = 0x10000000;
    const int GWL_STYLE = -16;
    const int GWL_EXSTYLE = -20;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var topmostWindowHandles = new ArrayList();
        EnumWindows(EnumWindowsCallback, topmostWindowHandles);

        var processesToKill = new HashSet<uint>();
        foreach (IntPtr hWnd in topmostWindowHandles)
        {
            uint processId = 0;
            GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, out processId);
            processesToKill.Add(processId);
        }

        foreach (uint pid in processesToKill)
        {
            Process proc = Process.GetProcessById((int)pid);
            Console.WriteLine("Killing " + proc.ProcessName);
            // kill process, except explorer.exe
        }
    }

    static bool EnumWindowsCallback(IntPtr hWnd, ArrayList lParam)
    {
        int exStyle = GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
        int style = GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE);
        if ((exStyle & WS_EX_TOPMOST) == WS_EX_TOPMOST 
            && (style & WS_VISIBLE) == WS_VISIBLE)
        {
            lParam.Add(hWnd);
        }
        return true;
    }

    public delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(IntPtr hwnd, ArrayList lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return:MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc lpEnumFunc, ArrayList lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, great. However, I guess, I've misunderstood `WS_EX_TOPMOST`. I am looking for windows which do not lose focus (e.g. VLC with "stay always on top" on). Most applications found by your method do not stay on top if another window is focused. Do you know by chance how to determine only those "stay always on top" windows?

Comment: `WS_EX_TOPMOST` is correct I believe. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx In addition, we probably have to check if the window is visible... I'm looking into that next...

Comment: @D.R. I added the check for visible windows. Try again now.

Comment: Thanks, did it myself in the meantime as well :-) Still I find three windows when there should be none: explorer (ok...), AppVStreamingUX (strange...) ipoint (strange...). Both do not have windows I can see, maybe I should check for the size as well...

Comment: Check with the Spy++ tool (should come with Visual Studio). Maybe there is another clue here.

Comment: BTW. Is your (original) question answered?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution which finds all processes with a topmost main window:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int WS_EX_TOPMOST = 0x00000008;
        int GWL_EXSTYLE = -20;
        foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            IntPtr hWnd = proc.MainWindowHandle;
            int res = GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
            if ((res & WS_EX_TOPMOST) == WS_EX_TOPMOST)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Topmost window found for process " + proc.ProcessName);
            }
        }
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);
}
```

This only checks if the **main window** of a process is topmost. I leave this answer because it might help with this specific problem (finding topmost main windows).

Comment: This assumes that only a process's main window needs to be checked. That's an assumption that could turn out to be valid, but it's not supported by anything in the question that I can see.

Comment: @hvd That's exactly what I noted below the code I posted. But you are right, that's an assumption which may not be correct.

Comment: Ah, I misread your note. It's not the case that all windows that aren't the main window are child windows. If you want to check all top-level windows, you will need to avoid starting from the processes' main windows entirely. A process may have multiple top-level windows, where none is a child of any other.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my note. I was hoping that @D.R. would give me feedback on this.